# Can I use Amazon in-app billing for device other than Amazon?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, in-app, amazon-appstore

Can I use Amazon in-app billing for device other than Amazon.  I have samsung galaxy tab 10.1 and Play Book. Will Amazon in-app billing work in these devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it was delivered via the Amazon market place it should work on all devices, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to publish across multiple markets, you can use [RoboBillingLibrary](https://github.com/christopherperry/RoboBillingLibrary). It handles in-app purchases across Google Play, and the Amazon Appstore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would work. If you are developing something for amazon app store then you can use Amazon Test SDK to test you IN App purchases. It is not necessary that the device has to come from Amazon to use Amazon IAP.